# How do I earn the Odinson hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

It's description says it's a secret hat.

How do you earn it?

[image]

Comment: If you get an answer it won't be secret anymore.

Comment: It hasn't been secret since about 5 minutes after the first person got it @MarounMaroun

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270794/223467

Comment: Don't be hating on my hat

Answer (score 5):

Spoilers for the discovered [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats/) are provided on MSE.

Here's a concise list of the known secret hats (images hidden behind links), along with spoilers on how to get them:

- Archimedes [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFidm.png) [how to get it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270791/295851)
- Onion Knight [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msq8o.png) [how to get it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270831/295851)
- Sun Wukong [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eInZ4.png) [how to get it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270870/295851)
- Hairboat’s Revenge [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14deA.png) [how to get it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270851/295851)
- 007 [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAIJ1.png) [how to get it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270837/295851)
- Odinson [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM1oS.png) [how to get it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270794/295851)

Comment: I just won odinson. I am soooo very tempted to click the link. But at the same time, I don't want to. *sigh*